# Интеграция telegram бота на Aiogram с jivo

Tags: python, aiogram

столкнулся с проблемой, нужно интегрировать telegram бота с jivo,чтобы он сохранил свой функционал бота. В документации Jivo указанно, что сервис общается с ботом по средству HTTPS запросов, то есть на бота отправляется запрос, методом POST в формате json, можете подсказать, как ловить эти запросы и высылать на них ответ?
Заранее, спасибо

Comment: Использовать вебхуки, у aiogram 2 вариации запуска бота, поллинг и вебхуки, вас интересует второе